# Finding return chars in unix filenames

Tags: linux, unix

This is part of a bigger problem but, of course, it's the bit that's giving me the most trouble.  So there's something going on with our users where they're creating files with return characters by doing something like this:

```
touch "tpseports
old"
```

That's another problem and not for me to mess with.  What I'm trying to do is find files like that with our script to remove outdated files.  Right now, we run a find command to place the old file names into a temp file and then remove based off of that list.  Something like this here:

```
find /home/userid \( -type f -a -mtime +365 \) 1>> TEMP

while read FILELIST
do
rm -f $FILELIST
done < TEMP
```

The problem is when we come across a file like:

```
/home/userid/tpseports
old
```

Because it will try to remove "/home/userid/tpseports" AND "old".
Has anybody run into something like this before and know the solution?  I'm still searching around the web for ideas so if I find a solution I'll post it here.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

`find` has the `-print0` option for cases like this:

```
find -type f -mtime +365 -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f
```

Comment: Problem is that -print0 doesn't seem to be available on AIX